# Python 3.4 error - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python

I'm in the early stages of learning python and following various online/training videos.

I'm running Python 3.4.x x64, using PyCharms in Windows.

In this particular example to learn how to use pysftp, the example script is to first upload a file to a server, and then the second part is to download a file from the server.

The first part (uploading a file to a server) worked perfect.  That function is now commented out.  The second part of the script is to now pull down this file from the server, and there is where the script is failing. I'm using the identical code as the example I'm following, so I am wondering if maybe my system is missing something.

Below is the script, and below that are the errors I saw when running in debugging mode using pdb:

```
import pysftp as sftp
#import pdb

def push_file_to_server():
    s = sftp.Connection(host='192.168.2.36',
                        username ='root',
                        password='xxxxxxx')

    local_path = "testme.txt"
    remote_path = "/home/testme.txt"
    s.put(local_path, remote_path)
    s.close()

#push_file_to_server()


#pdb.set_trace()

def get_file_from_server():
    s = sftp.Connection(host='192.168.2.36',
                        username ='root',
                        password='xxxxxxx')

    local_path = "testme.txt"
    remote_path = "/home/testme.txt"

    s.get(remote_path, local_path)
    s.close()

    get_file_from_server()
```

When I run the script using debugging, this is where in the debugging output I see an error:

...
...

```
> c:\python34\lib\logging\__init__.py(1877)shutdown()
-> h.flush()
(Pdb) n
> c:\python34\lib\logging\__init__.py(1878)shutdown()
-> h.close()
(Pdb) n
> c:\python34\lib\logging\__init__.py(1886)shutdown()
-> h.release()
(Pdb) n
> c:\python34\lib\logging\__init__.py(1869)shutdown()
-> for wr in reversed(handlerList[:]):
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> c:\python34\lib\logging\__init__.py(1869)shutdown()->None
-> for wr in reversed(handlerList[:]):
(Pdb) n
--Call--
Exception ignored in: <function WeakSet.__init__.<locals>._remove at 0x0000000003154158>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\_weakrefset.py", line 38, in _remove
  File "C:\Python34\lib\bdb.py", line 50, in trace_dispatch
  File "C:\Python34\lib\bdb.py", line 82, in dispatch_call
  File "C:\Python34\lib\pdb.py", line 249, in user_call
  File "C:\Python34\lib\pdb.py", line 345, in interaction
  File "C:\Python34\lib\pdb.py", line 1447, in print_stack_entry
  File "C:\Python34\lib\bdb.py", line 391, in format_stack_entry
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2236, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in __enter__
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I looked up the error a bit, with my limited knowledge it sounds like it's a complaint when arguments are missing in a function, but I don't know what to do differently and the first part of the script works fine when tested (uploading) and this is the same as that part just reversed and using get instead of put.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: When you run it normally, what's the traceback look like?

Comment: Is it your intent to call get_file_from_server() from within itself?  That's what your current indentation does.

Comment: Looking at the error message, it's telling you that your're trying to call `None` as if it were a function. The only function call in that line is `reversed()`. Therefore, the value of `reversed` must have been changed from the normal built-in function to `None`. Clearly that happens elsewhere in your code. Look for it.

Comment: When I run it normally, there are no errors except that it results in "Process finished with exit code 0"

Comment: BlivetWidget - that was it thanks! I removed the indent and it ran just fine. thanks so much.  First time posting on stackoverflow, trying to see how to pick your answer as the best answer...

Comment: @natv Glad it helped.  I didn't actually post an answer as such, I'll do that for you now to bring this to closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is whitespace-delimited, so unless you're working on a recursive function, change

```
def get_file_from_server():
    s = sftp.Connection(host='192.168.2.36',
                        username ='root',
                        password='xxxxxxx')

    local_path = "testme.txt"
    remote_path = "/home/testme.txt"

    s.get(remote_path, local_path)
    s.close()

    get_file_from_server()
```

to

```
def get_file_from_server():
    s = sftp.Connection(host='192.168.2.36',
                        username ='root',
                        password='xxxxxxx')

    local_path = "testme.txt"
    remote_path = "/home/testme.txt"

    s.get(remote_path, local_path)
    s.close()

get_file_from_server()
```